# Requiring the existence of a factorisation structure $(\cal{E},\cal{M})$ on $\bf{Top}$ that gives a specific reflective hull

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

I am looking for a factorisation structure $(\cal{E},\bf{M})$ (for sources as defined in Joy of Cats) on $\mathbf{Top}$ for which the following conditions hold:

$(1)\ $  $\bf{C}=\{ X\in \mathbf{Top}\ |\ |X|\leq 1\}$ is $\cal{E}$-reflective and

$(2)\ $ the $\cal{E}$-reflective hull of the two point discrete space is equal to the subcategory of all totally disconnected spaces, i.e., spaces for which the only connected subsets contain at most one point.

I am trying to find a counterexample to some result and have shown the following: If there is such a factorisation structure, then there exists a quotient map that is not in $\cal{E}$ and by using cocompleteness of $\bf{Top}$, it also follows that there is a source in $\bf{M}$ that is not a mono-source.

My guess (and I'm quite confident about it) is also that that if there is such a factorisation structure, then $\cal{E}$ should be a proper subclass of all quotient maps and all mono-sources should properly be contained in $\bf{M}.$

I have found a factorisation structure such that the second condition is satisfied, but it violates the first. My buest guess is to consider all(or maybe just some) factorisation structures $(\cal{E}_i,\bf{M}_i)$ such that $\bf{C}$ is $\cal{E}_i$-reflective. It can be shown that $\bf{C}$ is $\cal{E}:=\bigcap_I \cal{E}_i$-reflective and that $(\cal{E},\bf{M})$ is a factorisation structure for sources. The members of $\bf{M}$ are determined by the diagonalisation property or equivalently, a source $(f_j:X\rightarrow X_j)_J$ is a member of $\bf{M}$ if and only if whenever $(f_j)_J$ factorises through a morphism $e$ in $\cal{E}$, such as $(f_j)_J= (g_j)_J\circ e$, then $e$ is an isomorphism.

Even using these ideas, I'm having trouble determining whether the $\cal{E}$-reflective hull of the discrete two point space is equal to the category of all totally disconnected spaces. I have however shown that whenever $\bf{C}$ remains $\cal{E}$-reflective, then the reflective hull should be contained in the category of all totally disconnected spaces. The reverse inclusion is my problem. If you have any ideas, please let me know.